# Inserting polygon object into feature class using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geometry

How do I insert a polygon object into a feature class?

I've written the following code based off the Writing Geometries (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/writing-geometries.htm) guide, unfortunately all of those examples are starting from scratch and I extracted my polygon objects from the .getExtents().polygon function in the camera class. This creates the row and adds the name but there aren't any of the polygons.

```
for name, poly in polyDict.items():
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(gdb_fc, ['Name', 'SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
        cursor.insertRow([name, poly])
```

I've also tried adding an index to the poly variable to try the array but that doesn't work either. I'm obviously doing something wrong but have no idea as to what. I've tried it with a single value which doesnt work, I've tried extracting the XMax, YMax, XMin, YMin from the extent, I've tried 20 other things and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Assuming `poly` from your dictionary is a Polygon object then your insert cursor  retrieved fields would be `['Name','SHAPE@']`. Read the help file parameter section for the [insert cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm), you will read that SHAPE@XY is for a centroid but you want to insert a polygon.

Comment: I don't think SHAPE@XY is applicable with polygon feature classes, only points. You might need to delare your cursor with ['Name', 'SHAPE@'], construct your polygon from an array object as a polygon geometry and store that.. but first check that your dict actually has X,Y pairs and isn't empty.

Comment: @MichaelStimson and Hornbydd, you both had it correct! Needed to be the SHAPE@. I could have sworn I tried that earlier, but perhaps something else was not working at that time, but I'm seeing polygons now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To qualify as a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) I think the code that you present should include how you "extracted my polygon objects from the .getExtents().polygon function in the camera class"

Comment: @PolyGeo, OK will do in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Hornbydd](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416651/inserting-a-polygon-object-into-a-feature-class-in-arcpy#comment678193_416651):

> Assuming `poly` from your dictionary is a Polygon object then your
> insert cursor  retrieved fields would be `['Name','SHAPE@']`. Read the
> help file parameter section for the [insert
> cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm),
> you will read that SHAPE@XY is for a centroid but you want to insert a
> polygon.